# Firefox not detecting rgb colors in comparison operation

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have written a simple connect four style game using HTML, CSS, & javascript.  The game is fully functional in Chrome, but I get some funny behavior when using my Firefox browser.

In Firefox, the colors of the game board successfully change when a player drops a piece, however, when I do the comparison operation when checking if a player has won, Firefox does not detect the color whatsoever.

My attempt to fix the problem was by declaring a specific rgb value, instead of just saying 'purple', I did something like below, with similar results.

Here is just the relevant pieces of my javascript code:

```
const _purple = "rgb(124, 0, 132)";

columns[id][5 - pcs[id]].style.background = _purple;  // assignment works always
columns[id][5 - pcs[id]].style.background = 'green';  // assignment like this ok too

if (columns[_col][_row].style.background == _purple)  // only works in Chrome
if (columns[_col][_row].style.background == 'green') // only works in Chrome
```

I also tried to use `===` as was suggested by a friend.

***** UPDATE *****
I checked the console to see what Firefox was returning as was suggested in the first comment, and Firefox seems to be returning the correct values.

```
rgb(124, 0, 132) none repeat scroll 0% 0% 
green none repeat scroll 0% 0%
```

But the compare operation does not ever return true.
I attempted to just use this entire string, but that
did not work either.

As expected, on Chrome, if I just use
`"rgb(124, 0, 132)"` instead of `_purple`
it also returns true.

If it is of any help in resolving this issue
the CSS element(s) that I am using in the
game board is:

```
  .box {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
   }
```

Further:

visual studio reported back to me that "property color does not exist on type string". A call to `console.log(first.style.background.color);` returns `undefined` in my Firefox console, while a call to `console.log(second.style.background);` returns the correct rgb value. When comparing the undefined `.color` value it returns `true`, but it returns `false` when comparing the .background property, which is indeed the rgb value

Thank you for any help with this issue, the game and the attempts at correcting this error are viewable Here https://github.com/paolo-Rancati/four_in_a_sequence/tree/main/snippet

Comment: Add `console.log(columns[_col][_row].style.background);` and press F12 to bring up the browser console, and you can see what value Firefox is returning.

Comment: I added my reply to your comment into the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this using `computedStyle`, apparently the rgb value you have `"rgb(124, 0, 132)"` does not correspond to the one FireFox uses for `purple`.

```js
const _purple = "rgb(128, 0, 128)";

let first = document.getElementById("first");
let second = document.getElementById("second");
const spaces = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

first.style.background = "purple";
second.style.background = _purple;

console.log(window.getComputedStyle(first).backgroundColor);
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(second).backgroundColor);
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(first).backgroundColor === window.getComputedStyle(second).backgroundColor);
```

```css
div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/website.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Game Page</title>
</head>


<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

But **why** are you testing the colour of a cell?? You should instead have an array storing the state of the board, and test the values in the array! I know this does not answer your question, but you have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: It’s useful to call out XY problems. But you should provide that feedback in the comments, not as an answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney: I disagree in this case, because the asker explicitly wants to "check if a player has won", and this is the right answer to the real question...

Comment: I designed a game in Python where I did exactly that.  I am doing that in my program here as well, using the .box CSS class I then used querySelectorAll to create an array of all the boxes which made up the gameboard.  However, in this version of the game I kept the rows and columns separate and did not make a 2D array.  It was just done as a learning experiment.  The code itself is in a link above in a public repo.

Comment: @JerryPass: Okay, but in my opinion there is no point in such an experiment. Coding isn't just about getting the right output, but about robust implementation. Depending on setting some CSS and then checking it later is **not** robust at all and should never be done in use cases like yours, where the display should be **separate** from the game logic.